# Converting zip2john output to hashcat

Tags: hash, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I have video files stacked in zip and I forgot the password.

I want to use hashcat, because john will take much longer, but the hash from hash `zip2john` isn't compatible and I don't know how to convert it

Hash from `zip2john`:

```
  $zip2$*0*3*0*XX7486X3X6X2XX74ebba3e9f6119b6f9*5894*28e5fc64*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
...
```

Hashcat:

```
    C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\hashcat-6.2.6>hashcat 
    "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\try.txt"
    hashcat (v6.2.6) starting in autodetect mode
```

And this is the result:

```
    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545096 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545144 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545096 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545144 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545096 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545144 bytes

    Oversized line detected! Truncated 1355545096 bytes
```

these continues and I do not know if it is working.

However, john works

```
    C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\john-1.9.0-jumbo-1-win64\john-1.9.0- 
    jumbo-1-win64\run>john "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\try.txt"
    Warning: detected hash type "ZIP", but the string is also recognized as "ZIP-opencl"
    Use the "--format=ZIP-opencl" option to force loading these as that type instead
    Using default input encoding: UTF-8
    Loaded 1 password hash (ZIP, WinZip [PBKDF2-SHA1 256/256 AVX2 8x])
    Will run 4 OpenMP threads
    Proceeding with single, rules:Single
    Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
    Almost done: Processing the remaining buffered candidate passwords, if any.
    Warning: Only 30 candidates buffered for the current salt, minimum 32 needed for performance.
    Proceeding with wordlist:password.lst, rules:Wordlist
    Proceeding with incremental:ASCII
    0g 0:00:13:10  3/3 0g/s 19129p/s 19129c/s 19129C/s rynz2w..ry1581
    0g 0:00:13:13  3/3 0g/s 19134p/s 19134c/s 19134C/s rh18mr..rhs158
```

How do I convert the `zip2john` output to something hashcat can use?

Comment: Could you supply the output of `file <zipfile>` as well as `zip2john <zipfile>`? That would include the detected details of the file. Helps to speak directly about what is being detected so context can be provided around the hash.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x2DYYrKlgcVhDro9548XPhgCDjafRiFY/view?usp=drive_link) @signus . This is the output of the zip2john

Answer (score 1):

The output of zip2john is the correct format for hashcat. However, hashcat has a size limitation when cracking Winzip hashes, and it seems your file is too big.

More info:

- [zip file(s) problems](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-11466.html)
- [zip2 hash length issue · Issue #2302 · hashcat/hashcat](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2302)
- [Zip2john is incompatible with hashcat · Issue #2186 · hashcat/hashcat](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2186)
- [PKZIP: improve decompression and allow up to 320KB data length by philsmd · Pull Request #2053 · hashcat/hashcat](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/pull/2053)

Comment: 'Hashfile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt' on line 1 (try.zi...7af39bec0bdeda837a92f51f113b97d3): Separator unmatched' 

'Hashfile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt' on line 2 (try.zi...ced2c2c0258ebe6388911c83d32c91fd): Signature unmatched'

Comment: those are the result in hashcat that is why I thought that the hash is not compatible.